# Lagrange Multipliers for finding Geodesics on a Cylinder

Tags: differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations, geodesic

> Given a right circular cylinder:
>   \begin{align}
>     g(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2-1 = 0
> \end{align}
>   Use Lagrange multipliers to show that the geodesics on the cylinder are helices.

The Euler-Lagrange Equation is easy to set up, but how would one go about setting up the Lagrange Multiplier for this?

Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: It will help to translate the terms "geodesics" and "helices" into mathematical equations/inequalities that must be satisfied.

Comment: It is not very clear what the context of this problem is. How are the geodesics defined? Is it just for surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$? Do you have the metric already written in coordinates on the cylinder?

Comment: See "Example: Problem 6.4 – Part III" of http://teacher.pas.rochester.edu/PHY235/LectureNotes/Chapter06/Chapter06.htm

Comment: that link is now dead. here is a new link: http://teacher.pas.rochester.edu/PHY235/LectureNotes/Chapter06/Chapter06.pdf

Answer (score 1):

When you have a functional 
\begin{equation}
J[\gamma]=\int_a^b F(t,\gamma(t),\dot{\gamma}(t))dt
\end{equation}
restricted to the conditions $\gamma(a)=p$, $\gamma(b)=q$, and $g(\gamma(t))=0$ for all $t\in [a,b]$, if $g_x,g_y,g_z$ do not vanish simultaneously in $S:g(x,y,z)=0$ then there exists $\lambda$ a function in $[a,b]$ such that satisfies the following differential equation:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
F_x-\lambda g_x=\frac{d}{dt}F_{\dot{x}}\\
F_y-\lambda g_y=\frac{d}{dt}F_{\dot{y}}\\
F_z-\lambda g_z=\frac{d}{dt}F_{\dot{z}}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Since the geodesics are the critical points of energy functional, we have $F=\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2+\dot{z}^2$ and $g=x^2+y^2-1$. It follows that
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
-2\lambda x=2\dot{x}\\
-2\lambda y=2\dot{y}\\
0=2\dot{z}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}